# How to send Java spinner value to SQL? i want to Save it in date time format in SQL?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jspinner

First part is the button click part. second part is sql part

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    try {
        String id1 = jTextField1.getText();
        String subj = kk.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String name_teacher = tt.getText();
        String grde = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String st_d = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int en_d = jSpinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=class ";
        String username = "mali";
        String password = "12345";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        //String sub = kk.getText();
        //String gg =tt.getText();
        String QUERY = "INSERT INTO addteacher(id,sub,namet,grd,start_time,end_time)VALUES('" + id1 + "','" + subj + "', '" + name_teacher + "','" + grde + "','" + st_d + "','" + en_d + "')";
        st.execute(QUERY);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to do exactlly @Malinda Peiris

Comment: I want to send my jspinner data to sql as in date time format i have created my database columns.

Comment: It looks like you done it already no? the variables `st_d` and `en_d` inserted as `start_time` and `end_time`. what are you asking?

Comment: but it gives a error and dosent go to the sql table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
JSpinner hour = new JSpinner();
JSpinner min = new JSpinner();

//Your date format
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");

//Get values from your spinners
String HOUR = (String) hour.getValue();
String MIN = (String) min.getValue();

//Create a date 
Date parsed = format.parse(HOUR + MIN);
java.sql.Time sql = new java.sql.Time(parsed.getTime());

//Insert your date
System.out.println(sql);
```

Comment: Thank you but i want to send a selected time HH:MM to sql columns.

Comment: Thanks and lets say that my hour and minutes are in the same J spinner?

Comment: How is that happen, can you shouw us your GUI, or explain more please

Comment: your code worked i just did some edits thank you so much!

Comment: but in sql i can see a year also. i need only the time? i have given datetime format. do i have to change it??

Comment: so you should to change the type of your Date in the database